# iOS: Interactive animation with keyframes not resumed correctly on gesture end

Tags: ios, uikit, ios-animations

I'm trying to make an interactive dismissal animation, just like in the Youtube app.
The animation I have in mind is [here](https://share.icloud.com/photos/0BCqgby49hfOJnBmJILXyORJw) (sorry it's an iCloud link, but converting it to GIF it's over 2MB).

I'm using the standard `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` interface for the animator and `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`.

**Simplified version of my animator class:**

```
class MinimizeDismissAnimationController: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    var transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning!
    var dimmingView: UIView!
    var innerViewCopy: UIView!
    var playerCopy: YTPlayer!
    let interactionController: DismissalController!
    var tableSnapshot: UIView!
    var separatorView: UIView!
    
    var tabBarHeight: CGFloat!
    let playerMaxHeight: CGFloat = 250
    var playerResizeByInitial: CGFloat = 2
    var playerResizeByFinal: CGFloat = 2.25
    let playerMinimizedMultiplier: CGFloat = 0.3
    
    var playerHeightCon: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var playerTrailingCon: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var playerBottomCon: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    init(interactionController: DismissalController) {
      // stored here to be used by the transitioning delegate, doesn't have any specific purpose in this file
      self.interactionController = interactionController
    }

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        0.75
    }
    
    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        self.transitionContext = transitionContext
        
        let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) as! ViewController
        let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to) as! RootViewController
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        
        innerViewCopy = fromVC.view
        tabBarHeight = toVC.tabBarVC.tabBar.frame.height
    
        let duration = 0.75
        
        fromVC.view.isHidden = true
        let tabBar = toVC.tabBarVC.tabBar
        let tabBarSuperview = tabBar.superview!
        
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: .calculationModeCubic, animations: {
            self.animateImageMoveDown()
            
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.7, animations: {
                self.dimmingView.alpha = 0.75
                containerView.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
            
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                containerView.insertSubview(tabBar, aboveSubview: self.dimmingView)
                tabBar.frame = tabBar.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -self.tabBarHeight)
            })
            
            self.animateImageToBottomLeft()

            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.7, relativeDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                containerView.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }, completion: { done in
            tabBarSuperview.addSubview(tabBar)
            self.tableSnapshot.removeFromSuperview()
            self.dimmingView.removeFromSuperview()
            
            // TODO: some more cleanup of temporary views
            
            //self.transitionContext!.finishInteractiveTransition()
            //transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
            self.transitionContext = nil
        })
    }

    func animateImageMoveDown() {
        let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) as! ViewController
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        
        // not exactly copy, but still used to be animated to a different size 
        playerCopy = innerViewCopy.viewWithTag(ViewTags.video) as? YTPlayer
        containerView.addSubview(playerCopy)
        
        // details of the video below the player + related videos
        tableSnapshot = fromVC.relatedVideosTableView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)!
        tableSnapshot.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.addSubview(tableSnapshot)
        
        // dims the table snapshot as the animation progresses
        dimmingView = UIView()
        dimmingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        dimmingView.backgroundColor = .white
        dimmingView.alpha = 0
        containerView.addSubview(dimmingView)
        
        playerHeightCon = playerCopy.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: playerMaxHeight)
        playerTrailingCon = playerCopy.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor)
        let playerLeadingCon = playerCopy.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor)
        let playerTopCon = playerCopy.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.safeAreaInsets.top)
        
        // there's additional "separator" view with fixed height to be animated, but it's not part of this excerpt
        playerBottomCon = playerCopy.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -tabBarHeight-tabBarDividerHeight)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(playerCopy.constraints) // deactivate constraints from the original view controller
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            playerLeadingCon,
            playerTrailingCon,
            playerTopCon,
            playerHeightCon,
            
            // exactly below the player, contains video info and related videos
            tableSnapshot.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            tableSnapshot.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
            tableSnapshot.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: playerCopy.bottomAnchor),
            tableSnapshot.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: fromVC.relatedVideosTableView.frame.height),
             
            // placed exactly over the snapshot
            dimmingView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableSnapshot.leadingAnchor),
            dimmingView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableSnapshot.trailingAnchor),
            dimmingView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableSnapshot.bottomAnchor),
            dimmingView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableSnapshot.heightAnchor)
        ])
        
        // first recalculate frames (starting values for the animation in the keyframe)
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            containerView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
        
        // resize player a bit
        playerHeightCon.constant /= playerResizeByInitial
        
        // move it down, close to the tab bar
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([playerTopCon])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([playerBottomCon])
    }
    
    func animateImageToBottomLeft() {
        let containerView = transitionContext!.containerView
        
        // resize width, this is the final, minimized player width (check end of video in question)
        let newConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [
            playerCopy.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.widthAnchor, multiplier: playerMinimizedMultiplier)
        ]
        
        // in order to resize it, it shouldn't stretch to the container view's trailing
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([playerTrailingCon])
            
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(newConstraints)
        
        playerHeightCon.constant /= playerResizeByFinal // decrease height further
        playerBottomCon.constant = -tabBarHeight // position player exactly above the tab bar
    }
}
```

**The interaction controller:**

```
import UIKit

class DismissalController: UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition {
    var interactionInProgress = false
    private var shouldCompleteTransition = false
    private weak var viewController: UIViewController!
    
    init(viewController: UIViewController) {
      super.init()
      self.viewController = viewController
      prepareGestureRecognizer(in: viewController)
    }
    
    private func prepareGestureRecognizer(in vc: UIViewController) {
        // custom gesture recognizer, which allows vertical pans only
        let viewPan = PanDirectionGestureRecognizer(direction: .vertical, target: self, action: #selector(self.handleGesture(_:)))
        viewPan.delaysTouchesBegan = false
        viewPan.delaysTouchesEnded = false
        viewPan.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        
        let player = (vc as! ViewController).player
        
        player.addGestureRecognizer(viewPan)
    }
    
    @objc func handleGesture(_ gestureRecognizer: PanDirectionGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: gestureRecognizer.view!.superview!)
        
        // TODO: instead of 800, use dynamic value -> appr. ScreenHeight - SafeAreaTop - TabBarHeight
        var progress = (translation.y / 800)
        progress = CGFloat(fminf(fmaxf(Float(progress), 0.0), 1.0))
        
        switch gestureRecognizer.state {
        case .began:
            (self.viewController as! ViewController).player.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            interactionInProgress = true
            viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        case .changed:
            shouldCompleteTransition = progress > 0.35
            update(progress)
        case .cancelled:
            interactionInProgress = false
            cancel()
        case .ended:
            interactionInProgress = false
            if shouldCompleteTransition {
                finish()
            } else {
                cancel()
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

**My issue:**
If I release my finger early (5-10%), thus ending the pan gesture, the video player animates to the last keyframe values (when it's minimised and in the bottom left corner) but that should happen later, 70% through the animation. [Video here](https://easyupload.io/jowqhn)

You can see if I just move up and down my finger (interact) layout is updated correctly, with the expected values for the given percentage in time.
The issue is **reproducible when not using AutoLayout** as well (manually calculating frames). Also, the animation **works perfectly fine when it's not interactive** (performed on button tap let's say).